# Can't seem to get any Google Scripts code to work to BOLD all occurrences of one specific word

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting, google-apps

I found that RichTextValue should work, but I'm not sure where to put the word in on this code and when I use this code

```
function Bold() {
  for (var i = 4; i <=160; i++){
    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(i, 1);
    cell.setRichTextValue(SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
        .setText(cell.getValue())
        .setTextStyle(2, 16, SpreadsheetApp
          .newTextStyle()
          .setBold(true)
          .build())
        .build());
  }
}
```

I get an illegal argument error and I have no idea where I am going wrong. I am not a developer but got pretty good at VBA. Unfortunately I'm really battling with Google Scripts. Any help would be appreciated as this was the only thing I could not get right. Thank you!

Comment: Kindly share a sample spreadsheet and the desired output.

Comment: Are you aware that `setTextStyle(2, 16,...` mean set a style for letters from 2nd to 16th? Whatever the word(s) there is (are).

Comment: More information: Unfortunately I can't share the spreadsheet but I basically have 3 different types of cells in the spreadsheet. Cells with images, hidden cells (Contain FALSE value) and cells that start like this: ロ Recommendation: If, for any reason, you believe your blah blah blah. (this last cell type is straightforward TEXT. (Copied and pasted as values only) I'm trying to BOLD the word Recommendation in this tab on every occurrence of the word.

Comment: As I said, I've tried so many different scripts but am completely out of my depth here. This was just the last code I tried. :-( Thanks again for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the following code:

```
function testBold() {
  var boldStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).build();
  var cells = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Лист1!A1:A100');

  var values = cells.getValues();  // initial values
  var richValues = values.map(     // become rich values
    function(v) {
      var richBuilder = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(v[0]);
      if (v[0].length && v[0].length > 16) richBuilder = richBuilder.setTextStyle(2, 16, boldStyle);
      return [richBuilder.build()];
    }
  );

  cells.setRichTextValues(richValues);
}
```

At first, we avoid to read data from each cell sequencially, because there is more powerful way to read range data at once.

Further, we use the power of JS map() function to obtain desired rich styling for each input values array element. Do not remember to check input values to have string type and sufficient length before applying the style.

At last we write rich-style data back to the same sheet range.

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much. That definitely works. I'm just not sure how to get around the cells with images in them as they all just say: "Cellimage" now. Could I avoid those cells in the range or do I need another check? Thanks again.

Comment: If you can recognize "Cellimage" in code, then you can treat this case more carefully. You can use JS forEach(function(...) {...}) instead of map() and write data back to sheet conditionally inside the anonymous function excluding image data cells. It is not so quick as in previous code case, but it is useful for images to remain.